# Quality Center: Test Lab always showing the stats as Not Completed

Tags: quality-center

Running the test set from the Test Lab always showing the stats as Not Completed but when the same test is run using QTP or when the same script is opened in QTP and run, the status is shown as Pass in run result viewer screen.

Comment: I removed your email address from the post. Then answers should be provided via forum, not via emails

Comment: Which version of Quality Center/ALM are you using? Which version of QTP/UFT?